# How to change PHPUnit error messages to show custom errors

Tags: php, error-handling, phpunit

I have extended PHP Exception with my own to add additional data:

```
class MyException extends Exception {
   public $foo = [];

   public function __construct($message = '', $data = null, $code = 0) {
       $this->foo = $data;

       paret::__construct($message, $code);
   }
}
```

When doing normal requests these errors logs correctly and I do not want to add any additional content to `$this->message`.

---

When running test I can throw it:

```
if (!$this->save()) {
    throw new MyException('Internal Server Error', ['log' => 'missing data'], 500);
}
```

and PHPUnit will output:

> MyException: Internal Server Error

I want:

> MyExeption: Internal Server Error; {"log": "missing data"}

---

How to extend PHPUnit to be able to show `$myException->foo` along with error message?

---

*Sample code:*

```
<?php

class SampleTest extends CTestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->assertTrue($this->save());
    }

    protected function save()
    {
        $model = new Orders();
        $model->addError('id', 'ID is Required');

        if (!$model->validate()) {
            throw new HttpApiModelException(500, 'Failed to save', $model);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Executed with command `common/vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration tests/phpunit.xml --verbose tests/functional/SampleTest.php`

And output:

[image]

Comment: How you capture your exception ?

Comment: Can you show your PHPUnit test code.

Comment: @deoncagadoes I have framework `set_error_handler` that handles this error logging

Comment: @NigelRen Added strip down of test case. Imagine that `$this->save()` is actually some deeper methods call stack

Comment: Why exactly do you want to show this? You can use `expectException` to validate that the exception that you want to be thrown in thrown. Sounds like you want to add the message to the phpunit log to check it by hand? Sounds like an odd way of testing to me.

Comment: @DirkScholten To have more descriptive error message

Comment: In the phpunit logs? What is the point of that?

Comment: @DirkScholten When you write code to see what's actually wrong happened

Comment: Doesn't your exception already tell you that? Or are you using the tests as a debugging tool?

Comment: I've read it multiple times but I fail to see the point. It seems to me like you are trying to solve a simple problem in a really difficult way. That's why I'm asking what the exact purpose is.

Comment: @DirkScholten I think this is perfectly valid question because sometimes exceptions institute rich and valuable subsystem (just like events in DDD, and actually they are events). They could be not only caught, but processed, gathering info along there lifecycle. Having opportunity to easily access such information while development is an advantage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best option but you could implement test results printer, smth like:

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter;

class TestPrinter extends ResultPrinter
{
    protected function printDefect(\PHPUnit\Framework\TestFailure $defect, $count)
    {
        $this->printDefectHeader($defect, $count);

        $ex = $defect->thrownException();
        // you can do whatever you need here, 
        // like check exception type, etc,
        // printing just line number here
        $this->write('Line #' . $ex->getLine() . "\n");

        $this->printDefectTrace($defect);
    }
}
```

and register as a printer to be used (assume xml config but could be done via command line as well):

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         printerClass="Tests\TestPrinter"
>
    <!-- note printerClass attribute above -->
</phpunit>
```

Doing so, you would get output looking similar with:

```
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\SomeTest::testStuff
Line #16
LogicException: whatever
```

(I just made a simple test doing `throw new \LogicException('whatever');`)

Comment: To get original exception call `$e->getOriginalException()`

Answer (score 1):

So if you need this data to be printed everytime when you are running tests but not when it's on production then why not to extend the base Exception class and to check if you are under test environment then to concatenate the message and the data. And then all of your custom exceptions to extend this new Exception class.

```
class BaseException extends Exception {

   public function __construct($message = '', $data = null, $code = 0) {
       if (env('ENVIRONMENT') === 'test') {
           $message .= ' ' . json_encode($data);
       }

       paret::__construct($message, $code);
   }
}
```

But this implementation will require to change your MyException class to call the parent constructor with this data.

Instead of this

```
paret::__construct($message, $code);
```

Now you are going to have this

```
paret::__construct($message, $data, $code);
```

And also to extend the new `BaseException` class to these exception which you want to have this functionality

Comment: Currently I am using this **workaround**, just instead of `env('ENVIRONMENT')` I am using `strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 'phpunit')`. But my question is about extending/adding some hooks to PHPUnit itself

Comment: You mentioned you are using set_error_handler. why not implement it there